# Get aditionals parameters on wordpress URL of a post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following url (just as a normal post link on wordpress)

```
https://example.com/url-of-the-post
```

I need to add a pretty parameter on it and get it on the post.php.

I have found on stackoverflow doubts on how to get parameter via get like "?variable=x". Thats quite easy. But i need to get it via pretty url like:

```
https://example.com/url-of-the-post/parameter/value
```

I have my custom theme and i need it for an specific purpose. So i need those variables "parameter" and "value" into a PHP Variable.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!